# Make sure that a confirmation email is send only after user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments, devise-confirmable

I have added Devise with my Rails app and I am using the confirmable module. Then I integrated devise with Stripe.

I found out that when I try to register a user and the payment goes wrong, Devise still sends a confirmation email. When I check if a user was created in the rails console I found that no new user exists.  I don't understand why this happens. I feel like it wasn't suppose to be acting like that.

I found out about the [confirm!](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L59) method of devise but I am not sure how can I override it so that the user must first be created before sending this email.

Then I thought, the user might be created and because the payment failed to be destroyed then?! Not sure, I surely didn't code something like that.

Any tip or suggestion on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `skip_confirmation!` to send confirmation instructions later, just call it before saving the user record

```
@user.skip_confirmation!
```

You can send confirmation instructions later by using `send_confirmation_instructions` method

```
@user.send_confirmation_instructions
```

I don't know what exactly you are doing, but I can give you an example

```
@user.skip_confirmation!
if @user.save
  @user.send_confirmation_instructions
end
```

Comment: will do, just need to test it first!

Comment: I am getting an #<NoMethodError: undefined method `send_confirmation_instructions' for #<User:0x007fe2e95cd310>>

Comment: https://gist.github.com/stefioan/6c3477c741c801f2eb51 (that is the create method of registrations_controller.rb of devise)